# Change values of variables from other forms in real time

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change values of some variables in a form from another one.
I know how to pass it via constructors but that's not what I am looking for. I want to be able to pass it without changing the state of my forms.
I tried to make public variables in the initial form but I still can't access them from the other one to modify the value.

The first form is

```
public partial class Main : Form
```

and I have the variable:

```
public bool showingTexturePacks = false;
```

I tried to modify it from my second form (public partial class TexturePacksListViewer : Form) with a method:

```
private void TexturePacksListViewer_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Main main = new Main();
    main.showingTexturePacks = true;
}
```

It doesn't work..

Comment: where is your code    ?

Comment: I added a part of my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know how to pass it via constructors but that's not what I am looking for.

I assume here that you are passing properties defined on your form, not an instance of the form itself.

> I want to be able to pass it without changing the state of my forms. I tried to make public variables in the initial form but I still can't access them from the other one to modify the value.

If you pass an instance of one form to another, for example by passing it in the second form's constructor, you can access all of the public properties of the first form.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 form1) 
    {
        form1.Foo = 42;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code...

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Form2 f2 = new Form2(f1);
```

Note that the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) patterns support what you are trying to do in a powerful, generic way.  WPF is build around the MVVM pattern, though you can implement MVC or MVVM [with WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp) as well.

**UPDATE**

In the code you just posted

```
Main main = new Main();
main.showingTexturePacks = true;
```

You are creating a *brand new* instance of Main.  If you want to affect an instance already existing in your program, you need to pass in that already-existing instance somehow.

Comment: That was it :) I had to pass the form via constructor so I can change the variables. Thanks!